# CarouFredSel:Show hide div issue

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show, caroufredsel

I am trying to use CarouFredSel for to display different images in a div which needs to be hidden in the beginning and visible when some button is clicked later. But its not working as i expected.But when i set the div to visible in the beginning, then I can hide and show this div without problem.
So I am looking if someone can help me solve the problem hiding and showing CarouFredSel div.

### The CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    width: 92%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
    display:none;
}
.list_carousel {
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 0 0 30px 30px;
    width: 95%;
}
.list_carousel ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
}
.list_carousel li {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #999;
    text-align: center;
    width: 140px;
    height: 42px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.clearfix {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}
.prev {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.next {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

### The html to display CarouFredSel is like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="list_carousel">
            <ul id="foo2">
                <li>
                    <img src="images/itcells.png" s alt="" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/itcells.png" alt="" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/itcells.png" alt="" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/itcells.png" alt="" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/itcells.png" alt="" />
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>    <a id="prev2" class="prev" href="#">&lt;</a>
    <a id="next2" class="next"
            href="#">&gt;</a>

        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="hide" />
    <input type="button" id="show" />
</body>
```

### The jquery call is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#show').click(function () {    
        $(".wrapper").animate({
            "opacity": "show"
        }, 1000);    
    });
    $('#hide').click(function () {    
        $(".wrapper").animate({
            "opacity": "hide"
        }, 1000);    
    });    
});
$(function () {    
    //Scrolled by user interaction
    $('#foo2').carouFredSel({
        auto: false,
        prev: '#prev2',
        next: '#next2',
        pagination: "#pager2",
        mousewheel: true,
        swipe: {
            onMouse: true,
            onTouch: true
        }
    });    
});
```

Please help me to show and hide the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work I have change a few things (with working jsFiddle example, link after tutorial):

1. Remove an unused DIV
2. Update and clean CSS Style
3. Improved Carousel settings: with items, visible and scroll
4. Convert Carousel in function
5. Added values to the buttons
6. Added Placehold.it images for visual example
7. Updated Show and Hide functions to show Carousel

This is the result.

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">         
      <ul id="foo2">
           <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></li>               
           <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></li>  
           <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></li>  
           <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></li>  
           <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></li>  
           <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></li>  
           <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></li>  
           <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></li>  
       </ul>
       <a id="prev2" class="prev" href="#">&lt;</a>
       <a id="next2" class="next" href="#">&gt;</a>
 </div>         
 <input type="button" id="hide" value="hide" />
 <input type="button" id="show" value="show" />
```

## CSS

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background - color: white;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 50px;
    box - shadow: 0 0 5px #999;display:none;}
.clearfix {float: none;clear: both;}
.prev {position: absolute;z-index: 9;top: 50%;left:10px;}
.next {position: absolute;z-index: 9;top: 50%;right:10px;}
# foo2 {margin: 0;padding: 0;}
#foo2 li {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 100px;
        text - align: center;
        width: 100px;
        color: #8cabbf;display: block;}
# foo2 li img {border: 1px solid#dfe9ee;}
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#show').click(function () {
        $(".wrapper").animate({
            "opacity": "show"
        }, 1000);
        generateCarousel();
    });
    $('#hide').click(function () {
        $(".wrapper").animate({
            "opacity": "hide"
        }, 1000);
    });

    function generateCarousel() {
        //  Scrolled by user interaction
        $('#foo2').carouFredSel({
            auto: false,
            responsive: false,
            items: {
                visible: 3,
                width: 100
            },
            width: 600,
            prev: '#prev2',
            next: '#next2',
            pagination: "#pager2",
            swipe: {
                onMouse: true,
                onTouch: true
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**<kbd>[Here is a working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/aDG4S/)</kbd>**

Comment: You need to ACCEPT the answer so other users know that this POST it the correct one. Below the UP and DOWN button there is a CHECK mark. Please check it ;D

Comment: Now i understand. can u help me with another problem:): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808675/responsive-carousel

Comment: Sure. 2 things so you know you can VOTE UP awnsers to givr them more relevance or VOTE DOWN. The same for comments. Let's got to that one.